# Finding joint CDF of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> I can't seem to solve this exercise. I have that 
>   $$f_{XY}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
> 1, & 0 \leq x \leq 2,\space \max{\{0,x-1\}} \leq y \leq \min{\{1,x\}}\\[0.2cm]
> 0,     & \text{otherwise} 
> \end{cases}$$
>   I want to find the joint CDF.

I think I solved it for the case where $x \gt 2$ and $y \gt 1$, so that $$F_{XY}(x,y) = 1,$$ for $x \gt 2$ and $y \gt 1$, which I did through reasoning rather than by actually computing anything. After that I'm stuck.

I believe these are the rest of the cases:

1. when $x-1 \gt y$
2. when $x-1 \lt y \lt 1,\space 1 \lt x \lt 2$
3. when $0 \lt y \lt x,\space 0 \lt x \lt 1$
4. when $x \lt y,\space 0 \lt x \lt 1$
5. when $y \gt 1,\space 1 \lt x \lt 2$

I've failed in solving this for all those cases, which makes me think I probably have no idea how to find joint CDF's. For case $2.$, for example, I tried

$$F_{XY}(x,y) = \int_1^2 \left(\int_{x-1}^1 f_{XY}(x,y) dy \right)dx,$$ which doesn't give me the right answer. I have tried several other things, but nothing works for me, so any hints or advice would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try to draw the support of $f$? If you do it, you'll notice that $f$ is the uniform distribution on a parallelogram delimited by the points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$. Having that in mind, you should be able to solve the different cases just with considerations of areas, without calculating integrals.

Comment: No, I hadn't. But now I have at least managed to solve case 1. using your advice (and I'll continue trying to solve the rest). Thank you!

Comment: It becomes a lot more complicated for the other cases, I suspect that I'm supposed to use some other method, e.g. integrals, so the question remains. :p